# IIS Basic auth for certain path of my MVC-website

Tags: c#-4.0, iis, asp.net-mvc-4, iis-7.5

I want to protect one of the pages of my ASP.NET MVC4 (C#) website with [basic auth](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_access_authentication).

Can I do it with IIS 7.5 and how can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a blog post that shows you [how to incorporate basic authentication into an MVC 4 application](http://kevin-junghans.blogspot.com/2013/02/mixing-forms-authentication-basic.html).  This will work with IIS 7.5.

Comment: can it be done without modifying the application? Like i can do, for example, with python and nginx?

Comment: i really just need to add basic auth to a certain URL

Comment: You can do it for a certain URL by just using the custom authorize attribute on the controller action that represents that URL. You should be able to setup a basic auth in IIS so it will handle it, but I am not familiar with how to do that.

Comment: unfortunately, the goal is to do this with IIS only :(